# Least Squares Fitting Quadratic Equation to a set of points

Tags: quadratics, least-squares, regression-analysis

My math skills from my college days are a bit rusty, so if my terminology is wrong, I apologize.  I will try to be as clear as I can.

- I have a set of 50 points on a plane that roughly follow the pattern for a curve described by the function $y = ax^2 + bx + c$.
- I know I can use some sort of Least Squares Fitting algorithm to determine the best possible a, b, and c values.
- "Math" language confuses the heck out of me at times.  I've tried Googling for an answer to how to accomplish this, but everything seems to start off simple, then delve into theory involving partial derivatives and things I can't seem to follow to save my life.
- I have a basic understanding of matrices.

My understanding based on what I have been able to get from online sources is that I can set up two matrices:

```
| {r1c1} {r1c2} {r1c3} |     | {y1} |
| {r2c1} {r2c2} {r2c3} |     | {y2} |
| {r3c1} {r3c2} {r3c3} |     | {y3} |
```

And then perform basic matrix operations so that my first matrix ends up being an identity matrix, and if I do the same operations to the other matrix, the resulting values are my a, b, and c values.

My questions are:

- Is my understanding and approach incorrect?  If okay, awesome!
- How do I use the 50 X and Y values to derive values for {r1c1} and {y1} and so on?

All the examples I find seem to want to show an example of 50 equations and 50 unknowns.  I can't seem to find an example using 50 data points fitted to 3 unknowns, so all the i, n, k, talk of degrees, etc.  just leaves me boggled - .  the article [Least Squares Fitting--Polynomial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastSquaresFittingPolynomial.html) for example.  Don't I need a 3 by 3 matrix to find a solution since I have 3 unknowns?

I thought based on what I was reading, that the values should be (sorry about the programmer-ish symbols, not sure how to make math symbols in the post):

```
| {Sum(1:50, x[i]^0)} {Sum(1:50, x[i]^1)} {Sum(1:50, x[i]^2} |  | {Sum(1:50, y[i]*x[i]^0} |
| {Sum(1:50, x[i]^1)} {Sum(1:50, x[i]^2)} {Sum(1:50, x[i]^3} |  | {Sum(1:50, y[i]*x[i]^1} |
| {Sum(1:50, x[i]^2)} {Sum(1:50, x[i]^3)} {Sum(1:50, x[i]^4} |  | {Sum(1:50, y[i]*x[i]^2} |
```

And then performing matrix operations on both matrices so that the left matrix ends up being the identity matrix and the right matrix ends up with my values for a, b, and c.  But my results are wildly different than what Excel produces.

So either I am doing something wrong, or there is an error in my program to do this.  Anyone that can make sense of this, please help!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the mistake is to forget to inverse the matrix.

To make it understandable, a molre general example is shown below. Then, it is shown in the case of the quadratic function.

Note that $[M]^{-1}$ means the inverse of the matrix, not $\frac{1}{[M]}$.

[image]

Comment: Just to be clear, if I take the inverse of the matrix, and then perform operations to reduce it to the identity matrix and perform those same operations on the left-hand matrix, then my left-hand matrix will contain the values I am looking for?

Comment: I don't realy understand what you mean. Just do the operations as shown on sheet above. First compute the 3X3 matrix. Second : compute the matrix inverse. Multiply it by the vector on the right. You obtain the $a,b,c$ approximates. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MatrixInverse.html

Comment: JJacquelin, my apologies for being confusing.  I come from a programmer's background, not a mathematician's background :-)

Comment: JJacquelin, my apologies for being confusing.  I come from a programmer's background, not a mathematician's background :-) I am trying to follow examples I find online that allude to using something I think called Gaussian elimination.  I think I might be getting myself confused from that.  I was somewhat under the impression that if I perform operations on the inverse matrix to transform it into the identity matrix, and perform those same operations on the matrix on the left, that the equation would still hold true.  I guess I am wrong.

Comment: In order to better understand each other, we need to name the objects involves. Let $[M]$ be the 3X3 matrix made of 9 sums. Let $[V]$ be the column vector made of 3 sums. Let $[X]$ be the column vector made of the three unknowns $a,b,c$. The system of three linear equations to be solved is $[V]=[M].[X]$.  You are not obliged to use the inverse matrix if you know how to compute $[X]$ with another method.You can use your prefered method as you like.